# Get author(user) in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication, authentication

I'm trying to make a news posting app using ModelForms, and currently I'm trying to set it so that the form automatically gets the authenticated user so when said user posts the news item, their name will appear, like "Posted By: User". In the models.py file, I've tried using: `models.ForeignKey(User)`, but it doesn't automatically set the user and it makes a drop-down widget appear in the form. It is not working correctly.

How would I achieve what I'm trying to do, which is as stated earlier:

1. Get the authenticated user who is posting the form
2. Post his name on the page with the news item

Posting code on request:

Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class NewsItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    news = models.TextField(max_length=100000)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.user, self.date, self.news)

class NewsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsItem
```

Views.py:

```
from news.models import NewsForm
from django.forms import forms
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def news_poster(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = NewsForm()
    return render(request,'news_post.html', {'form': form})
```

template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}News poster {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="/news/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: post relevant code from your models, forms and views and template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu can use `instance` to pass the user

```
from news.models import NewsForm, NewsItem
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def news_poster(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        item = NewsItem(user=request.user)
        form = NewsForm(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = NewsForm()
    return render(request,'news_post.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2):

## Models

Add a `ForeignKey` to `User`:

```
class NewsItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateField()
    news = models.TextField(max_length=100000)
```

## Forms

Exclude the `user` field form the `NewPostForm` so it doesn't show up as a select.

```
class NewPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewsItem
        exclude = ('user',)
```

## Views

Before saving the `NewPostForm`, add the user:

```
if form.is_valid():
    news_item = form.save(commit = False)
    news_item.user = request.user  # User posting the form
    news_item.save()
```

Comment: Will try this out, give me a couple minutes to integrate

Comment: @JohnGarza Let me know how this works. I updated the code to match your posted code.

Comment: The field disappears, but when I try to submit, it raises an Integrity error. "news_newsitem.user_id may not be NULL"

Comment: @JohnGarza Did you modify the view, and use `form.save(commit = False)`? If you did: is your user actually authenticated, or is it anonymous?

Comment: User is logged on, according to the template output I have. I logged out and logged on again using django's packaged views. I did use form.save(commit = false) as well

Comment: @JohnGarza If everything looks as posted, you can look at the django debug page to figure why `news_item.user` is not an user (and see what it is equal to)

Comment: Is this still the "way to go"? It looks unsanitary to have to set the user in the view. Shouldn't there be a way to have a model-level setting which sets the user to the currently logged on user?